# Regaining access to TimerTask when app is restored back from background

Tags: android, multithreading, handler, timertask

I have a ClockView that is displaying time using a TimerTask and handler, the issue is when app is placed in background and restored it looses communication with the handler and TimerTask, below is my timer task

```
timer = new Timer();
    if (mCurrentRadian > 0 && !mStarted) {
        isPaused = Boolean.FALSE;
        timerTask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.d(TAG, "TimerTask");
                handler.obtainMessage().sendToTarget();
            }
        };
        timer.schedule(timerTask, 1000, 1000);


    }
```

My Handler:

```
 private Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        Log.d(TAG, "handleMessage");
        super.handleMessage(msg);

};
```

Everytime I close the app I can see the both `TimerTask` and `handlerMessage` tag messages in logcat but do not know how I can regain control and continue obtaining the results,

Comment: So every second the message under object msg is printed?

Comment: yes it is, I came up with a solution, using moveTaskToBack(true) which makes the app's back button act like a home button it works but thats not a guarantee i need a solid machanism